# Bash, argument list segment

Tags: bash, arrays

If you have a list in python, and you want the elements from 2 to n can do something nice like

```
list[2:]
```

I'd like to something similar with argv in Bash. I want to pass all the elements from $2 to argc to a command. I currently have

```
command $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
```

but this is less than elegant. Would would be the "proper" way?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

you can do "slicing" as well, `$@` gets all the arguments in bash.

```
echo "${@:2}"
```

gets 2nd argument onwards

eg

```
$ cat shell.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "${@:2}"

$ ./shell.sh 1 2 3 4
2 3 4
```

Comment: You should also wrap it in double-quotes to avoid problems with spaces in arguments (e.g. `echo "${@:2}"` would work properly when called with `./shell.sh 1 2 "multi-word argument" 4 5`).

Comment: Worth noting that this supports length as well, i.e. `"${@:start:len}"`

Comment: Can you also give a default value if `${@:2}` is empty?

Answer (score 4):

Store `$1` somewhere, then `shift` and use `$@`?

Comment: good suggestion, but i think an operation on a list would be more elegant

Answer (score 4):

script1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@"
```

script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
shift
echo "$@"

$ sh script1.sh 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 
$ sh script2.sh 1 2 3 4 
2 3 4
```

Comment: This is a great solution, in particular to get subcommands options!

Comment: Please double-quote `$@` (e.g. `echo "$@"`) to avoid weird parsing. See ["I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) and ["When should I double-quote a parameter expansion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion)