# How to remove first bash argument and pass the others to another command?

Tags: bash, parameter-passing

In bash `$@` contains all the arguments used to call the script but I am looking for a solution to remove the first one

```
./wrapper.sh foo bar baz ...:

 #!/bin/bash

 # call `cmd` with bar baz ... (withouyt foo one)
```

I just want to call `cmd bar baz ...`

Comment: See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390738/bash-argument-list-segment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`shift`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html) to shift the argument array.  For instance, the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $@
shift
echo $@
```

produces, when called with `1 2 3` prints `1 2 3` and then `2 3`:

```
$ ./example.sh 1 2 3
1 2 3
2 3
```

Comment: Please double-quote `$@` (e.g. `echo "$@"`) to avoid weird parsing. See ["I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) and ["When should I double-quote a parameter expansion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion)

Answer (score 3):

`shift` removes arguments from $@.

> ### shift [n]
>
> Shift positional parameters.
>
> Rename the positional parameters $N+1,$N+2 ... to $1,$2 ...  If N is
>      not given, it is assumed to be 1.
>
> Exit Status:
>      Returns success unless N is negative or greater than $#.

Answer (score 1):

Environment-variable-expansion! Is a very portable solution.

Remove the first argument: with $@

```
${@#"$1"}
```

Remove the first argument: with $*

```
${*#"$1"}
```

Remove the first and second argument: with $@

```
${@#"$1$2"}
```

Both $@ or $* will work because the result of expansion is a string.

links: 

[Remove a fixed prefix/suffix from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623835/remove-a-fixed-prefix-suffix-from-a-string-in-bash)

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#ARGLIST

Variable expansion is portable because it is defined under gnu core-utils

Search for "Environment variable expansion" at this link:

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/