# How to read multiple words as one argument

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, arguments

I am trying to write a shell script that takes the first word given to it as one argument and anything that comes after it as a second argument.

The user must call my shell script and provide their arguments in one line from the terminal: shellscript.sh word1 word2 word3 ...... wordn
How can I write my script such that

arg1 = word1

arg2 = word2 - wordn?

Comment: This might help: `help shift`

Comment: I would recommend making it the caller's responsibility to construct the 2nd argument:  `shellscript.sh word1 "word2 word3 ..."`.

Comment: See [Bash, argument list segment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2390738/4154375).

Answer (score 1):

Use `shift` to remove the first argument, and use `"$*"` to concatenate the remaining ones.

```
#!/bin/bash
first=$1
shift
rest="$*"  # Assuming the first character of $IFS is a space.

printf '<%s>\n' "$first" "$rest"
```

Comment: Note that you are changing `IFS` globally; assignments don't themselves take pre-command modifiers.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, fixed.